# How can I convert a class files from a Java Applet to something usable without a browser?

Tags: java

Went to a website and gathered 5 class files that work for a java applet. I have Eclipse and want to be able to put these class files in there and launch the applet. How do I do that? In addition, is there a way to use an applet without a browser?

Answer (score 1):

Java comes with something called the [applet viewer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html) which will let you run a jar with an Applet class.  In effect it is a minimal browser with just the Java plugin.  Here are the steps I took to run a class downloaded from the web as an applet found [here](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~sbj/examples/Java-examples-basic/Greeting/Greeting.html):

I started by creating a simple html file (called `example.html`) that pointed to the applet class:

```
<applet code="Greeting.class"
        width=200
        height=200>
</applet>
```

Then I downloaded the associated `.class` file into the same folder as the `example.html` (found [here](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~sbj/examples/Java-examples-basic/Greeting/Greeting.class)).  Then I executed the applet with this command:

```
appletviewer example.html
```

Comment: How do I get a jar? I have 5 classes and no jar file.

Comment: A jar is just a zip file with your `.class` files, you could also just run appletviewer with your class files in the classpath.  Creating a jar is also easy: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by run it with my class files in the classpath? It doesn't allow me to run any classes.

Comment: I added code that will take class files and an applet tag and run it with the appletviewer

Answer (score 1):

put your stuff in Eclipse, right click on the java file which extends Applet (this the entry point of the program like the class has the main method) and click "Run as Applet".... Here is an exmple :

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you run an applet from Eclipse if you just have the class files? I guess if you create an empty project and add them as a lib, but then what would you click on to "Run as an Applet"?

Comment: Tried this but the class files need to be java files, I think? It doesn't do anything when I run.

Comment: yep, you need java file. maybe you need decode it and put it there to run.The one which extends Applet is the one you can run

Comment: True, you could run a decompiler like [JD](http://jd.benow.ca/), the code might be hard to read but it should execute with the same behavior as the original class files.

Comment: Okay I tried this. It gives me the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at SampleDistApplet.start(SampleDistApplet.java:44)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)